# Jboss Fuse pack Protocol exception

Tags: java, exception, jboss, containers, jbossfuse

while running my fuse application, the JVM is throwing below error. It seems to be related to port exception, but i couldn't find anything. Can someone help.

```
   jvm 1    | org.eclipse.jgit.errors.PackProtocolException: want 596eb6cfefe4b2aed58ba2b3241e47f862989b11 not valid
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.parseWants(UploadPack.java:1190)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.processHaveLines(UploadPack.java:1063)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.negotiate(UploadPack.java:1043)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.service(UploadPack.java:744)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.upload(UploadPack.java:666)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.InternalFetchConnection$2.run(InternalFetchConnection.java:93)
    jvm 1    | Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 596eb6cfefe4b2aed58ba2b3241e47f862989b11
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:145)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader$1.open(ObjectReader.java:299)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk$2.next(RevWalk.java:971)
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.parseWants(UploadPack.java:1176)
    jvm 1    |      ... 5 more
    jvm 1    | ERROR: io.fabric8.patch.patch-management (1): want 596eb6cfefe4b2aed58ba2b3241e47f862989b11 not valid
    jvm 1    | org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: want 596eb6cfefe4b2aed58ba2b3241e47f862989b11 not valid
    jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    jvm 1    |      at io.fabric8.patch.management.impl.GitPatchRepositoryImpl.cloneRepository(GitPatchRepositoryImpl.java:288)
    jvm 1    |      at io.fabric8.patch.management.impl.GitPatchManagementServiceImpl.ensurePatchManagementInitialized(GitPatchManagementServiceImpl.java:1826)
    jvm 1    |      at io.fabric8.patch.management.impl.Activator$StartLevelNotificationFrameworkListener.frameworkEvent(Activator.java:241)
```

Comment: From the exception, you seem to be using Fuse Fabric, and there seems to be issues in syncing your git repos if you having ensemble nodes. If you are using the latest version, please execute, fabric:git-synchronize -a to make all git repos in sync. The problem above means that the git commit, 596eb6cfefe4b2aed58ba2b3241e47f862989b11 performing the action is deleted or does not exist. Hence, please also check with, 'git log 596eb6cfefe4b2aed58ba2b3241e47f862989b11'

Comment: This is a standalone setup and i dont have any dependencies with GIT. The same binary works when running locally and having this issue when instantiating from Docker Container.